# Could it be an issue if I remove/replace the heatsink and don't clean the thermal paste?

Tags: desktop-computer

I removed my heatsink and didn't clean off the existing thermal paste.
I reattached it then left it for 4 days -  will cause any problems?

Comment: Was the old paste dry & crusty? Was it apart in the air for 4 days, or together but off, or on & running for 4 days? Paste is paste, if it's still there maybe it's still working fine. Are temps higher now than before? Is the computer still working OK?

Comment: actually yes i just ordered a thermal paste (deep cool Z5) it will be delivered  on monday it was dry as hell though i will replace it soon as possible tnx

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the 'paste'.  Some of them are really just paste.  Others are designed to reflow when heated (so they will fill in all the spots you miss when applying it and the imperfections in the heatsink and CPU package lid).  Still others reflow and then harden like an adhesive to help keep the heatsink in place.

For the kind that hardens, *always* replace it, simply because once it's hardened, you can't easily put the two pieces back together again after taking them apart without significantly impacting the thermal conductivity.

For the first kind (just paste), you should usually just replace it.  It's very easy if you're not careful to accidentally introduce air bubbles that will then impact thermal conductivity, and because it doesn't reflow the bubbles will usually not dissipate over time.

For the kind that reflows though, it depends on whether it's dried out or not, and whether or not you have reason to believe it's been physically contaminated.  If it's dried out, just clean it off and reapply new paste (after decontaminating the surfaces too).  If you think it might be contaminated (sat in open air for a couple of days, was exposed in a really dusty room, touched it with an ungloved hand or something that could leave behind particulates), you should probably replace it too.